# Need guide on Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Its my first time to work with Joomla and I need to make a plugin that basically stores/updates a `name` and a `City` the thing is that I want this functionality only in admin panel not in the front end.

Its a bit confusing to me weather I should create a component or a module or a plugin ?

Does anyone has a good guide on how to create such functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has also been asked at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/22514/120

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know when to use a module, a plugin, or a component, then a good starting point would be [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_(general_definitions)).

Typically, a module is essentially used for displaying content on specific pages in a specific location. A plugin usually works in the background (modifies displayed content, computes stuff, alters the database, processes payments, etc...). A component is like the Joomla articles component (com_content), in most cases, a component occupies the biggest part of the page (while a module occupies a smaller part).